# sql statement select from DB limit didn't work

Tags: php, mysql

i have a question which is my limit statement didn't work i want the content select from database and limit the show content in 40 only but it didn't work

here is my SQL statement with php code

```
$chatroomID=$_GET['chatroomID'];
$userID = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM chatroom_chat WHERE chatroom_id ='$chatroomID'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $chat = $row['chat_id'];

    $sql3 ="SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = '$chat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,40
    ) sub
    ORDER BY id ASC ";

    $getChatData = mysqli_query($connection,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

   /*here have statement to get username*/

    while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($getChatData)) {
        echo "<div>all content</div>";
    }

}
```

does my code have any syntax error? i no sure why it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = '$chat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40
        ) sub
        ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Does your code shows fatal error when you run it?
Assuming you have `$connection` set properly, and you are querying the right database tables, 
I cant figure out any syntax error. Just that for int type columns in my database table I dont use single quotes.
So I write queries as follows

`
if(!empty($chat)){
$sql3 ="SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = $chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,40
    ) sub
    ORDER BY id ASC ";
    $getChatData = mysqli_query($connection,$sql3) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
}
`

Comment: What is the manifestation of the error? What do you see on screen? Have some hint? 

e.g. Ok can you provide me the sql query using `echo $sql3; die();`

Comment: @Aditya this things show up `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = '107' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,40 ) sub ORDER BY id ASC`